# Associated type defaults on trait

Tags: types, rust, traits

How can we overcome the problem of associated type defaults when we need a type that depends on other type in a trait?

```
    trait Foo{
        type C;
        type K = Vec<Self::C>;
    }
```

```
error[E0658]: associated type defaults are unstable
  |
3 |     type K = Vec<Self::C>;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
   = note: see issue #29661 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29661> for more information
```

Comment: Have you considered using the nightly compiler? But the fact that the default depends on another type doesn't seem to be the issue here, but just that associated type defaults are unsable so it is feature-gated.

Comment: @rodrigo yes, I can use the flag #![feature(associated_type_defaults)] in nightly to compile it, but I would like to avoid unsafe/unstable code by all means if it's possible. This rename is just for aesthetic to not type Vec<Self::C> here and there. That's why I wanted to know if there's an idiomatic way to achieve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that it depends on another associated type is irrelevant. Providing defaults for associated types is not yet a supported feature at all.

```
trait Foo {
    type K = i32;
}
```

```
error[E0658]: associated type defaults are unstable
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     type K = i32;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: see issue #29661 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29661> for more information
```

You can compile with nightly and enable the `associated_type_defaults` feature if you want to use the current (unstable) implementation, which does work for your case:

```
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]

trait Foo {
    type C;
    type K = Vec<Self::C>;
}
```

I'm not sure I'd recommend it though just based on what the tracking issue indicates is incomplete, but that's up to you.

---

That all being said, this shouldn't be a *"problem"*. Sure having defaults available could be convenient, but its not required. Just specify it when implementing the trait:

```
trait Foo {
    type C;
    type K;
}

impl Foo for i32 {
    type C = i32;
    type K = Vec<Self::C>;
}
```

Comment: thank you. It was confusing since it was still depending on the type C, but I understood where the problem was.